# R data into column stock symbols

Tags: r, transformation, variable-length

I'm downloading stock data with 5 symbols in stock_list. The following code works:

```
stock_list <- c("ZM", "XLNX", "XEL", "WDC", "WDAY")

master_df <- NULL
for (idx in seq(length(stock_list))){
  stock_index = stock_list[idx]
  getSymbols(stock_index, verbose = TRUE, src = "yahoo") 
  temp_df = as.data.frame(get(stock_index))
  temp_df$Date = row.names(temp_df)
  temp_df$Index = stock_index
  row.names(temp_df) = NULL
  colnames(temp_df) = c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close", 
                        "Volume", "Adjusted", "Date", "Index")
  temp_df = temp_df[c("Date", "Index", "Open", "High", 
                      "Low", "Close", "Volume", "Adjusted")]
  master_df = rbind(master_df, temp_df)
}
```

The stock symbols are also in "data" from excel; 1 column, 5obs. Details show the following: Factor with 5 levels.

**How can I transform the data and write for example stock `list <- c(xy)`, so that I don't have to write the symbols manually into the list?**

So I tried:
`stock_list <- c(data)`

Console shows:

```
*$ï..Nasdaq5Symbole
[1] ZM   XLNX XEL  WDC  WDAY

Levels: WDAY WDC XEL XLNX ZM*
```

**And how can I solve the length problem (see error below) ??**

```
*Error in attributes(.Data) <- c(attributes(.Data), attrib) : 
  'names' attribute [5] must be the same length as the vector [1]*
```

Comment: Try `stock_list <- as.character(data[[1]])`

Comment: Your column may be getting read in as a single factor as opposed to multiple. Try this as well: `stock_list <- strsplit(data, split = " ")[[1]]`

Comment: @GregorThomas: Thanks a lot! `stock_list <- as.character(data[[1]])` worked perfect for me. Have a nice day :)

Comment: @JustinSingh: Thanks for your answer! I get a "non-character argument" error, because the data are not characters.